# Spark DataFrame change datatype based on column condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one Spark DataFrame df1 of around 1000 columns all of String type columns. Now I want to convert df1's columns' type from string to other types like double, int etc based on conditions of column names. For e.g. let's assume df1 has only three columns of string type

```
df1.printSchema

col1_term1: String
col2_term2: String 
col3_term3: String
```

Condition to change column type is if col name contains term1 then change it to int and if col name contains term2 then change it to double and so on. I am new to Spark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply map over columns, and cast the column to proper data type based on the column names:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = Seq(("1", "2", "3"), ("2", "3", "4")).toDF("col1_term1", "col2_term2", "col3_term3")

val cols = df.columns.map(x => {
    if (x.contains("term1")) col(x).cast(IntegerType) 
    else if (x.contains("term2")) col(x).cast(DoubleType) 
    else col(x)
})

df.select(cols: _*).printSchema
root
 |-- col1_term1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col2_term2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col3_term3: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi @Psidom I tried your approach it seems it changed types but it changed name as well I get printSchema like cast(col1_term1 as integer): integer (nullable = true)

Comment: What spark version are you using? I didn't get the behavior in spark 2+. You might try `alias`. `col(x).cast(IntegerType).alias(x)` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

While it wouldn't produce any different results than the solution proposed by **@Psidom**, you can also use a bit of `Scala`'s *syntactic-sugar* like this

```
val modifiedDf: DataFrame = originalDf.columns.foldLeft[DataFrame](originalDf) { (tmpDf: DataFrame, colName: String) =>
  if (colName.contains("term1")) tmpDf.withColumn(colName, tmpDf(colName).cast(IntegerType))
  else if (colName.contains("term2")) tmpDf.withColumn(colName, tmpDf(colName).cast(DoubleType))
  else tmpDf
}
```

Comment: How would you do it if you had a nested dataframe with StructTypes and ArrayStructs? In my case, I need to process a deeply nested schema and what I need to do is to convert every column that is a StructType which matches a specific column in a list into an ArrayStruct.